# account creation by department

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to bulk create accounts by tying them by their Department in PowerShell. I'm currently using `if..elseif..else` script and it just won't work for me. Within the department code `if..elseif` will then break out by two different `if` statements depending if the account begins with 'x' or 'y' they need separated due to different account settings. Some department codes will begin in 0's as well. I simplified my scripts by putting the commands in quotes.

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "C:\Createuser.csv"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $Displayname = $User.LastName + ", " + $User.Firstname
    $ContractorDisplayname = $User.LastName + ", " + $User.Firstname  + " (Contractor)"
    $UserFirstname = $User.FirstName
    $UserLastname = $User.LastName
    $ContractorLastName = $User.LastName + ".Contractor"
    $Department = $User.Department
    $Description = $User.Description
    $OU = $User.OU
    $SAM = $User.SAM
    $Password = $User.Password
    $Manager = $User.Manager
    $ManagerName = Get-ADUser -Identity $Manager -Properties samaccountname

    if ($Department -in '005','367','RR1','411') {
        if ($SAM -like 'x*') {".\GoldenContractorADscript.ps1"}
        if ($SAM -like 'y*') {".\GoldenADscript.ps1"}
    } elseif ($Department -in 'S11','222','054') {
        ".\StratasADscript.ps1"
    } else {
        if ($SAM -like 'x*') {".\StandardContractorADscript.ps1"}
        if ($SAM -like 'y*') {".\StandardEmployeeADscript.ps1"}
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to use `-in` / `-notin` with an array on the RHS, such as in  `$Department -in '005', '367', 'RR1', '411'`.

Comment: @mklement0 I changed it and it's getting closer to working. it just now defaults it to the ".\StandardContractorADscript.ps1" command which has the -notin.
So it looks like this:
     Elseif($Department -notin '6HU','367','RR1','411','S11','222','054'){".\StandardContractorADscript.ps1"}

  Else{".\StandardEmployeeADscript.ps1"}

Comment: What is the actual value of `$Department`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I've edited the code. $Department = $User.Department but I have over 600 departments so the values will vary. does that help?

Comment: I can see that you define `$Department = $User.Department`. That was not the question. Is the updated code from your question the code you're currently running? Because you're still using `-eq` where you should be using `-in` (and with an array of values). If not, please update your question with the actual code you currently have.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the clarification. It is now updated!

Comment: I just tested a minimal example of your code, and depending on the department and the first character of the account name the correct script names are echoed. If it doesn't work for you, please a) actually describe the problem, and b) provide sample input that would allow us to reproduce your problem. In your question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers sorry for the delay but the -in/-out made it work. Thanks for your help!